# Import C/C++ function into C#

Tags: c#, c++, c

I have some C code which will be called from C# using P/Invoke. I am trying to define an C# equivalent for this C function.

```
SomeData* DoSomething();

struct SomeData
{
    ...
}
```

How do I import this C method to C#? I am having trouble defining the return type of the function.

**EDIT:**
i had a bunch of functions to import. This is one which had me stuck.

```
[DllImport("SomeDll.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr DoSomething();
```

I thought about using IntPtr, even if its the right way what after that?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: i had a bunch of functions to import. This is one which had me stuck.

[DllImport("DoremiSource.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr DoSomething();

I thought about using IntPtr, even if its the right way what after that?

Comment: @ShaQ.Blogs Might want to add that information to your question and expand on it a little.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand your question but I'll give a shot at answering it. You need to define the structure that is being returned from your C function and use [Marshal.PtrToStructure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ca6d5z7.aspx) to use the returned structure.

```
[DllImport("SomeDll.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr DoSomething();

public struct SomeData
{
    //...
}

//code to use returned structure
IntPtr result = DoSomething();

SomeData structResult = (SomeData)Marshal.PtrToStructure(result, typeof(SomeData));
```

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing that what you are trying to achieve is the following:

1. Your C/C++ native method takes no parameters and returns a pointer to a structure.
2. The C# equivalent is to return an IntPtr (pointer).

The problem is that you cannot resolve the IntPtr to the structure in C#

...research this:

Marshal.PtrToStructure(IntPtr, Type)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ca6d5z7.aspx

You can wrap your code up like so

```
public static class UnsafeNativeMethods
{
   [DllImport("SomeDll.dll")]
   private static extern IntPtr DoSomething(); //NO DIRECT CALLS TO NATIVE METHODS!!

   public static SomeData SafeDoSomething()
   {
      try
      {
         return (SomeData)Marshal.PtrToStructure(DoSomething(), typeof(SomeData));
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
         //handle exception
      }
   }
}
```